# Why are the regions being highlighted when I mouse over on them?

Tags: theming

On each region hover over the region is highlighted with a background colour of light blue and the border changes to red.
I cant work out whats causing this (i'm a newbie).
Im using a base theme of ninesixty and only have a few additional modules installed.
Its not a browser addon as I see the same thing in firefox and chrome.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a debugging feature that this theme uses. Disable this line (or similar) in ninesixty.info by adding a semicolon before it.

```
stylesheets[all][] = styles/framework/debug.css
```

Then clear caches for example on this page: admin/config/development/performance